# Vlookup with multiple columns and rows

Tags: excel, vlookup, excel-365

I am looking for a solution to allow the below VLOOKUP code to loop and return all results in a table meeting the criteria in D2.. I have found several pages that have parts or other use case solutions but not one that fits issue this directly. Any help would be appreciated.

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D$2,Table1[#All],{3,5,6,7,8,9},FALSE),"")

This formula returns the data I need just need it to loop to other instances of the data in the table and return those as well.

Comment: Please include which version of excel you are using. Excel formulas do not loop in the same way that VBA does, for a formula to return multiple results it must be an array formula and behavior will change dramatically depending on excel version.

Comment: Using excel 365